# ubuntu script to cp from one directory to another

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I am writing a script to do the following task
I have directories like this.

/home/users/ac

/home/users/nf

/home/users/tu

/home/users/ms

.
.
.
N

Inside of every directory there are 2 folders one is Data and another es Backup, like this.
/home/users/ac/Data
/home/users/ac/Backup

The script  I have so far is this.
find . -name Data -type d -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2

but what I need is one script that copy everything is located inside Data “dynamically inside all directories under /home/user* ” to the Backup directory of each user. For example something like this.

cp /home/users/ac/Data/* /home/users/ac/Backup

and I need something automatized that loop every user under /home/users/* and copy data from Data directory to Backup directory for every user.

I will really appreciate any help thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3):

A simple application of a `for` loop and `cp -R` will fix your problems

```
cd /home/users
for i in ./*; do cp -Ra "$i"/Data/* "$i"/Backup/; done
```

Comment: Everything you have so far is available in all POSIX shells so should work* without modification in many other shells.  Of course, the same errors will also occur in every other POSIX shell.  To fix them, quote every occurrence of `$i`, so they become `"$i"`, and use `./*` not `*' just to be safe (even though it may be unnecessary if all user directories are simply 2 ASCII lower case letters it is always good practice to be safe).  Otherwise a good answer (+1).  Also, perhaps consider the `--preserve=all` or `-a` options with `cp` since this seems to be a backup script.

Comment: @Jose Luis Rodriguez Salas Don't forget to accept the answers that work the best for you. (There's a big outline of a checkmark by each answer, click that to accept the answer it's next to.)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at using rsync to do this.  It's easily scripted and you can use cron to run your script whenever.  I used to use a utility called mirrordir a long time ago for this, but it's not in the Ubuntu repositories anymore.

A quick search turned up this tutorial:  http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/unix/nix_rsync/index.html